# Spring data jpa - conversion types before every @Query executed - is it possible?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently using Spring data Jpa 3.0.4 with Hibernate 6.1.7 final.
I have a simple Query for testing:

```
    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(t) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM Teacher t " +
            "JOIN t.user u " +
            "WHERE u.role.id = :idRole")
    boolean test(RoleId idRole);
```

Now, as you can see i passed "RoleId" object as parameter which contains Long of id object (it's a simple wrapper).
In "Role" entity, id field is of Long type, so what i need is to tell spring "Before executing method with "RoleId" parameter, unwrap it and pass unwrapped Long value"

Role entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@IdClass(RoleId.class)
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "role_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "role_id_seq", sequenceName = "role_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Role(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public RoleId getRoleId() {
        return RoleId.wrap(id);
    }
```

I got this error without any type converters:

```
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.CoercionException: Cannot coerce value `.wrapper.RoleId@3d` [.wrapper.RoleId] as Long
```

Is it possible to achive it in spring data jpa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SpEL notation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).

```java
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(t) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM Teacher t " +
            "JOIN t.user u " +
            "WHERE u.role.id = :#{#role.id}")
boolean test(@Param("role") Role role);
```

I don't know if `@Param` is still needed in newer versions (I work with SpringBoot 2.x) to use the parameter by its name, but you might want to try it anyway. Note that the named param used within `@Query` comes from the "argument"(?) of `@Param`, not the function's parameter name. In other words, if the signature were `boolean test(@Param("role") Role userRole);`, you'd use `role` in `@Query`.

If you don't want to use `@Param` and the query doesn't work, the `@Param`-less `@Query` would be

```java
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(t) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM Teacher t " +
            "JOIN t.user u " +
            "WHERE u.role.id = ?#{[0].id}")
boolean test(Role role);
```

Which is not as readable IMO.